# Reproduce example pivottable.js in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pivottable.js

I am trying to reproduce the example of pivottable.js in jupyter notebook (here https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/jupyter_pivottablejs/tree/master/example) but I get an error :

Code (df is a pandas dataframe from a mps.csv in link above)

```
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
pivot_ui(df,
   cols= ["Party"],
   rows= ["Province"],
   rendererName= "Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart",
   rowOrder= "value_z_to_a", 
   colOrder= "value_z_to_a",
   rendererOptions= {
       "c3": { "data": {"colors": {
           "Liberal": '#dc3912', "Conservative": '#3366cc', "NDP": '#ff9900',
           "Green":'#109618', 'Bloc Quebecois': '#990099'
       }}}
    }
)
```

Error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-accb72869b19> in <module>()
 12         "c3": { "data": {"colors": {
 13             "Liberal": '#dc3912', "Conservative": '#3366cc', "NDP": '#ff9900',
---> 14             "Green":'#109618', 'Bloc Quebecois': '#990099'
 15         }}}
 16     }
TypeError: pivot_ui() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cols'
```

TypeError: pivot_ui() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cols'

I tried using 'columns' instead of 'cols' and it did not work.

Thanks for your help!

Here a screenshot of the jupyter notebook
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g55gd.png)

Comment: There seem to be a bug in what has been installed. I got the same error as you after installing the module via conda. Checking the source file the function pivot_ui seem to accept no keyword arguments. I created an issue on github and will get back here if I get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the name `pivottablejs` is overridden by some old version on conda and the original author is trying to solve this...

But it works if installing with `pip` instead.

So run `conda remove pivottablejs` and then `pip install pivottablejs` and it should work.

Comment: (library author here) This is correct, and it's a real shame! Please vote on this issue to help build support for resolving the situation: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/pivottablejs-airgap/issues/3